# Django 1.6 - "The outermost 'atomic' block cannot use savepoint = False when autocommit is off."

Tags: django, transactions

In the django 1.5- days, if I wanted to manually manage transactions (or transactions within transactions), I would do something like this:

```
@transaction.commit_manually
def my_method():
    master_sid = transaction.savepoint()
    for item in things_to_process:
        inner_sid = transaction.savepoint()
        # Make changes, save models, etc.
        ...
        if I_want_to_keep_this_iterations_changes:
            transaction.savepoint_commit(inner_sid)
        else:
            transaction.savepoint_rollback(inner_sid)
    if I_want_to_keep_all_un_rolled_back_changes_from_loop:
        transaction.savepoint_commit(master_sid)
    else:
        transaction.savepoint_rollback(master_sid)
```

If I'm understanding [the Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/transactions/#s-id5) correctly, when upgrading to Django 1.6+, I should change the above to something like this:

```
def my_method():
    transaction.set_autocommit(False)
    try:
        # Same code as above
    finally:
        transaction.set_autocommit(True)
```

However, in Django 1.6+, if you call model.save() while autocommit is False, Django will raise the following error:

> TransactionManagementError: The outermost 'atomic' block cannot use
>   savepoint = False when autocommit is off.

So, how do I save a model while autocommit is false?
**What's the modern replacement for my old, Django 1.5 code?**

Comment: Use @transaction.atomic  on method

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use *transaction.atomic()* instead:

```
def my_method():
    with transaction.atomic():
        for item in things_to_process:
            with transaction.atomic():
                # Make changes, save models, etc.
                ...
                if I_want_to_roll_back_this_iterations_changes:
                    raise Exception('inner rollback')
        if I_want_to_roll_back_changes_from_loop:
            raise Exception('mater rollback')
```

*transaction.atomic()* will handle the commit and rollback, and it can be nested.

[Relevant docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/transactions/#django.db.transaction.atomic)

Answer (score -1):

You should read [controlling transactions explicitly](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/transactions/#controlling-transactions-explicitly).

specially

> If you attempt to run database queries before the rollback happens, Django will raise a TransactionManagementError. You may also encounter this behavior when an ORM-related signal handler raises an exception.

and

> You may use atomic when autocommit is turned off. It will only use savepoints, even for the outermost block, and it will raise an exception if the outermost block is declared with savepoint=False.